# flask: How to store and retrieve POST calls?

Tags: python, flask, flask-cache

```
@app.route('/path/<user>/<id>', methods=['POST'])
@cache.cached(key_prefix='/path/<user>', unless=True)
def post_kv(user, id):
    cache.set(user, id)
        return value

@app.route('/path/<user>', methods=['GET'])
@cache.cached(key_prefix='/path/<user>', unless=True)
def getkv(user):
    cache.get(**kwargs)
```

I want to be able to make POST calls to the path described, store them, and GET their values from the `user`. The above code runs, but has bugs and doesn't perform as needed. Frankly, the flask-cache docs aren't helping. How can I properly implement cache.set and cache.get to perform as needed?

Comment: You can do this manually, it should be very simple. What are you trying to cache, full post request by path, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flask, implementing your custom cache wrapper is very simple.

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache, MemcachedCache

class Cache(object):

    cache = SimpleCache(threshold = 1000, default_timeout = 100)
    # cache = MemcachedCache(servers = ['127.0.0.1:11211'], default_timeout = 100, key_prefix = 'my_prefix_')

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, key = None):
        return cls.cache.get(key)

    @classmethod
    def delete(cls, key = None):
        return cls.cache.delete(key)

    @classmethod
    def set(cls, key = None, value = None, timeout = 0):
        if timeout:
            return cls.cache.set(key, value, timeout = timeout)
        else:    
            return cls.cache.set(key, value)

    @classmethod
    def clear(cls):
        return cls.cache.clear()

...

@app.route('/path/<user>/<id>', methods=['POST'])
def post_kv(user, id):
    Cache.set(user, id)
    return "Cached {0}".format(id)

@app.route('/path/<user>', methods=['GET'])
def get_kv(user):
    id = Cache.get(user)
    return "From cache {0}".format(id)
```

Also, the simple memory cache is for single process environments and the SimpleCache class exists mainly for the development server and is not 100% thread safe. In production environments you should use MemcachedCache or RedisCache.

Make sure you implement logic when item is not found in the cache.

Comment: Thanks so much, this taught me a lot.